# for loop in R using if & print

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, for-loop

Maybe I'm thinking too hard on this but I need to create a for loop & if statement to find the highest value in my data set. We also have to write a print statement that prints it out & the day. There's 93 rows & 4 columns in the initial matrix. Column 4 has the needed data. The days are in column 1.

I don't know programming at all. So far this is what I got:

I created a vector out of the column with the data:

```
only.data <- c(data[,4])
```

Here's my feeble attempt at a `for` & `if` statement:

```
for (counter in 1:93) {
  if (only.data >= data[,4])
    print (only.data)
}
```

How do I get it to spit out the highest value using this method? It prints the max value 93 times and that's not what I want. Do I need to create the `only.data` vector or can I use the original matrix? I also need to print out the corresponding date next to the highest value.

ps - I know I can use the `max` function which is much quicker but that's not the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are cheating, thus I won't post a full solution here, but only point you in the right direction

1. `data[,4]` is already a vector and there is no reason whatsoever to use `c()` on it. There is also no reason to save it in a new object `only.data`, although it potentially can make your loop faster as it won't need to index in each loop.
2. The idea of a loop is that you will use an index in it (although you don't have to, but there is no real reason not to). Thus, you are specifying the index in `for()`. Although you specified an index (`counter`), you haven't used it, thus your loop prints `only.data` regardless of anything you are doing.
3. All your `if` doing is to check if `only.data >= only.data` in every iteration (which is obviously unnecessary)
4. To calculate the maximum in a loop is not such an obvious thing, as you comparing a single value in each iteration, thus you''ll need some strategy. For example, you could create a dummy variable which will be compared in each iteration against `only.data[counter]` to check if it's bigger, and then be replaced in case it's not

To illustrate my last point, consider a toy example

```
set.seed(1)
only.data <- sample(10,10)
only.data
#[1]  3  4  5  7  2  8  9  6 10  1
```

You can see that the maximum value is in the 9th position, now we will assign the first value of this vector to a dummy variable and will try to use a `for` loop in order to find the maximum

```
dummy <- only.data[1]
dummy
## [1] 3

for (counter in only.data) {
  if (counter > dummy) dummy <- counter
}

dummy
## [1] 10
```